# VBA: Runtime Error 1004 debugging - pulling weather data from API into an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, xml, vba, api, spreadsheet

I'm using the "[How to build a simple weather app](https://codingislove.com/weather-app-in-excel-vba/)" tutorial from Coding Is Love, with slight tweaks.

I'm getting an error 1004 when running.

**My Macro**

```
Sub Weather()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String, xmlresponse As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

myurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?apikey=4a2360d14bf33378079d2e2d49e35ddb&mode=xml&units=imperial&q=new%20york"

xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
xmlresponse.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)

Sheets(1).Range(B2).Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/temperature/@value")(0).Text
Sheets(1).Range(B3).Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/precipitation/@mode")(0).Text
Sheets(1).Range(B4).Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/wind/speed/@name")(0).Text

End Sub
```

Where do I need to make changes for it to print the values I'm looking for (@value @mode @name)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Sheets(1).Range("B2")`

Comment: Also you may just declare `xmlresponse As MSXML2.DOMDocument60` without `New` keyword and replace the line `xmlresponse.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)` with `Set xmlresponse = xmlhttp.responseXML`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!